# jquery добавить код после изменения текста в div

Tags: jquery

Значит есть div, в него после отправки формы приходит результат работы формы(в нем появляется текст). Как при изменении этого div'a добавить вконец x?

пробовал так:

```js
$('.wpcf7-response-output').bind( 'DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
 var input = $('.wpcf7-response-output').html();
 input += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
 $('.wpcf7-response-output').html(input);
});
```

```html
<div class="wpcf7-response-output"></div>
```

Но получается рекурсия и зависает страница.

Comment: `приходит результат работы формы` - вот там и добавляйте в конец 'x'. Там же, где результат работы формы добавляется в div

Comment: Без понятия, это делает плагин contact from 7 для wordpress) непонятно куда он там все сует)